# TypeScript arguments of union of functions are transformed to "never"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have few different interfaces. Each of them contains property called `type`.

```
interface Type1 { type: 'key1', name: string }
interface Type2 { type: 'key2', description: string, name: string }
interface Type3 { type: 'key3', cost: number }
```

mapping interface

```
interface TypeMap {
   key1: Type1,
   key2: Type2,
   key3: Type3
}
```

And union type

```
type TypeElement = Type1 | Type2 | Type3
```

Map object, that uses record of each type separately. Each record in the function has its own type. Just like the mapping interface

```
const allTypes: { [key in keyof TypeMap]: (record: TypeMap[key]) => void } = {
   key1: (record) => {},
   key2: (record) => {},
   key3: (record) => {},
}
```

When I pass a variable of type `TypeElement` into a callback from `allTypes`, it gives me an error

```
const func = (record: TypeElement) => {
   const cb = allTypes[record.type]
   return cb(record)
}
```

Here `cb` type is `((record: Type1) => void) | ((record: Type2) => void) | ((record: Type3) => void)`
But when I try to call it `cb(record)` it tells that `cb` type is `(record: never) => void`

The error is:

*Argument of type 'TypeElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
The intersection 'Type1 & Type2 & Type3' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type 'Type1' is not assignable to type 'never'.*

**Why I get that error? What is wrong with that? How I can pass record to `cb` without giving me an error?** `record as never`, `as any` are not the solutions I am looking for!

Comment: `func` should also be generic for that to work

Comment: @Dimava can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Type1 { type: 'key1', name: string }
interface Type2 { type: 'key2', description: string, name: string }
interface Type3 { type: 'key3', cost: number }

interface TypeMap {
   key1: Type1,
   key2: Type2,
   key3: Type3
}

type TypeElement = Type1 | Type2 | Type3

const allTypes: { [key in keyof TypeMap]: (record: TypeMap[key]) => void } = {
   key1: (record) => {},
   key2: (record) => {},
   key3: (record) => {},
}

const func = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(record: TypeMap[K]) => {
   const cb = allTypes[record.type as K]
   return cb(record)
}
```